# Evaluating the limit as one variable of a two variable function defined as a series goes to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This was a question on a qualifying exam that I took, and it was tripping me up.

Define $$f(x,y) = \sum_{n} \frac{x}{x^2+yn^2}.$$ Show that $g(y) = \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x,y)$ exists for all $y > 0$, and find $g(y)$.

I was trying to think about it as a Riemann sum before taking the limit. The fact that we need $y$ strictly greater than $0$ led me to rewrite it as 
$$
\sum_{n} \frac{x}{x^2+yn^2} = \sum_{n} \frac{1}{(\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}n})^2+1}\frac{x}{(\sqrt{y}n)^2},
$$
and so I had a feeling $\arctan$ might be involved. Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you prove the limit exist?

Comment: I didn't unfortunately. If user316353's answer is the only straightforward way to do it, then I wouldn't have been able to anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evaluate the infinite series explicitly. Starting from the Mittag-Leffler expansion of the cotangent $$\pi \cot(\pi z) = \frac{1}{z} + 2z \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{z^2 - n^2},$$ it follows that $$f(x,y) = -\frac{x}{y} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(ix/\sqrt{y})^2 - n^2)}$$ $$=-\frac{x}{y} \cdot \frac{1}{2 i x / \sqrt{y}} \Big(\pi \cot(i\pi x / \sqrt{y}) - \frac{1}{(i x / \sqrt{y})}\Big)$$ $$= \frac{\pi}{2 \sqrt{y}} \coth\Big(\frac{\pi x}{\sqrt{y}} \Big) - \frac{1}{2x}.$$ You can get the answer using $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \coth(x) = 1.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wasn't familiar with the Mittag-Leffler expansion of cotangent, but it looks like a fairly nice formula.